# Css: getting the width of an img

Tags: html, css

Well, my question is quite basic: how can I get the width of an img tag wihing my css file?

I'm working with a header and it has and  tag. Now, this is what i have in my css:

```
.header > img {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50vw - 273px);
    z-index: 20;
}
```

And it basically tells the image where it has to be inside my header using `calc()` where my second parameter is the img width. So, how can i get the img width so i don't have to hardcode half of the size right there?

Comment: You can use JavaScript for that! For instance, you can use  document.querySelector(). I can provide a longer snippet if you need an example.

Comment: `50%` is half the width.

Answer (score 1):

CSS is not programming language, you don't "get" the width. The things you write into "left" are relative to container, so writing 50% there won't help. I think you can get the correct result with:

```
.header > img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50vw;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 20;
}
```

See also http://jonrohan.codes/fieldnotes/vertically-center-clipped-image/ although that talks about moving the image vertically.

Comment: Works great! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to do this is css or html, but you can use javascript to get the image width with the following code if you have an image id tag.

```
<script>document.getElementById('whatever your image id').width</script>
```

if you put this code in html, just do

```
<p><script>document.write(document.getElementById('whatever your image id').width)</script></p>
```

to display the image width. I'm not sure if there is a way to link javascript to css
so that you do not have to hard-code the value for the width in css. But if anyone does find a way, let me know!

Thanks.

Comment: You realize `document.write` overrides the entire page, right?

Comment: Yeah. Good point. Don't think it will override the entire page if I wrap it around in some html tags though.

Comment: The problem is that I can't use javascript.

Comment: Oh that's unfortunate.. Here is a link that might help with html, css, and javascript if anything here is worth helping with images. https://www.w3schools.com/ But other than that I would just hardcode if you absolutely cannot use javascript. Funnily enough I also looked at Honza's solution and it seemed doable, but unfortunately it didn't work. I would try playing around some more to see if you have closed any tags to see why it didn't work one last time. But other than that I really don't know how else to approach this problem. If you find out let me know. Thanks!